# Why Play Framework uses JSON why MongoDb uses BSON

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework, bson

I encountered many troubles of dealing with serializing/deserializing Scala data types to/from JSON objects and then store them to/from MongoDB in BSON form.

1st question: why Play Framework uses JSON why MongoDb uses BSON.

2nd question: If I am not wrong, Javascript does not have readers and writers for serializing/deserializing BSON from MongoDB. How can this happen? Javascript can seamlessly handle JSON, but for BSON I expect it needs some sort of readers and writers.

3rd question: (I read somewhere) why Salat and ReactiveMongo uses different mechanisms to talk to MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a widely used format for transfer data in this days. So pretty good to have it "from the box" in the web framework. That is the reason Play has it.

The same reason mongo use it - it is a good idea to store data in the same format as user query it and save it. So Why mongo use BSON but JSON ? Well, BSON is the same as JSON but have additional properties on every value - data length and data type. The reason of this - when you are looking a lot of data (like db query do) you need to read all the object in JSON to get to another one. We can skip reading in the case if we will know the length of the data.

So You just do not need any BSON readers in JS (it could be somewhere but rarely used) because BSON is format for inside DB usage.

you can read [this article](https://www.compose.io/articles/from-json-to-bson-and-back/) for more inforamtion